# Application Confidentiality

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-search, ethics, applications

I applied for a job and then made it to being one of the two finalists. I asked on the application that my current employer not be notified. After I did not receive the job a memo was then put out to all the department heads at the prospective employer saying I had been one of the finalists and even the day I had interviewed. The memo got forwarded to me the day after it was released. I don't want my current employer finding out I was applying for new jobs. If I can get it sent to me how easy would it be for someone to send it to my current employer. What should I do about this?

Comment: Most people know to not contact a previous employer unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

> What should I do about this?

Your best bet is probably to contact the hiring manager, and reiterate your desire for confidentiality.

Something along the lines of "I see this memo was sent to all the department heads. While I was really excited to be a finalist, I do want to make sure that everyone, including these department heads and anyone else who is notified here, understands my desire that this remain confidential. I'm sure you can appreciate my position." might work.

As I'm sure you understand, once more than a few people know something, it's hard to keep it quiet. So contact them soon.

Comment: I was a finalist. I didn't get the job. They then published the memo after the job was accepted by the other finalist. I'm hesitant to make waves as there is another position they asked me to apply for. But it does make me question their professionalism.

Comment: It is a local government job so I think there was the idea to address "openness" of the hiring process, but I too thought it strange and unprofessional to send a memo naming the external runner-up (me).